# Get Record Per Month But Also Get Zero If No Records That Month

Tags: mysql

If I have the following SQL Table

Tests

```
id   type   receiveDate
 1   Blood   2012-01-18
 2   Blood   2012-01-20
 3   Blood   2012-01-18
 4   Blood   2012-03-01
 5   Blood   2012-05-21
 6   Blood   2012-05-18
 7   Blood   2012-06-14
 8   Blood   2012-07-22
 9   Blood   2012-07-29
 10  Blood   2012-12-04
 11  Blood   2012-12-30
```

And I run the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Tests 
WHERE YEAR(receiveDate) = '2012' 
GROUP BY MONTH(receiveDate)
```

I will get back

```
COUNT(*)
 3
 1
 2
 1
 2
 2
```

The question I have, is there a way to get back all twelve months even if there are no records for that month? So for example I would like to get the output of

```
COUNT(*)
 3
 0
 1
 0
 2
 1
 2
 0
 0
 0
 0
 2
```

Also, as an added bonus is there a way to display the month WITH the count? 
Thank You!

Comment: Done any research? Something like https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+get+rows+for+month+for+which+no+data+exists or similar?

Comment: added bonus? I would have thought that that was a basic requirement :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  Months.m AS month, COUNT(Tests.receiveDate) AS total FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 as m 
    UNION SELECT 2 as m 
    UNION SELECT 3 as m 
    UNION SELECT 4 as m 
    UNION SELECT 5 as m 
    UNION SELECT 6 as m 
    UNION SELECT 7 as m 
    UNION SELECT 8 as m 
    UNION SELECT 9 as m 
    UNION SELECT 10 as m 
    UNION SELECT 11 as m 
    UNION SELECT 12 as m
) as Months
LEFT JOIN Tests  on Months.m = MONTH(Tests.receiveDate)  
GROUP BY
    Months.m
```

If you want year specific then try this.

```
SELECT  Months.m AS month, COUNT(Tests.receiveDate) AS total FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 as m 
    UNION SELECT 2 as m 
    UNION SELECT 3 as m 
    UNION SELECT 4 as m 
    UNION SELECT 5 as m 
    UNION SELECT 6 as m 
    UNION SELECT 7 as m 
    UNION SELECT 8 as m 
    UNION SELECT 9 as m 
    UNION SELECT 10 as m 
    UNION SELECT 11 as m 
    UNION SELECT 12 as m
) as Months
LEFT JOIN Tests on Months.m = MONTH(Tests.receiveDate)  
AND YEAR(Tests.receiveDate) = '2012'
GROUP BY Months.m
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach giving all the results for the year in one row.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 1, 1,0)) as Jan,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 2, 1,0)) as Feb,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 3, 1,0)) as Mar,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 4, 1,0)) as Apr,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 5, 1,0)) as May,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 6, 1,0)) as Jun,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 7, 1,0)) as Jul,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 8, 1,0)) as Aug,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 9, 1,0)) as Sep,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 10, 1,0)) as Oct,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 11, 1,0)) as Nov,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 12, 1,0)) as `Dec`
FROM test 
WHERE YEAR(receiveDate) = '2012' 
  AND type = 'Blood'
```

The result is

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
3   0   1   0   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   2
```

And if you want to report more than one type for the year

```
SELECT type,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 1, 1,0)) as Jan,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 2, 1,0)) as Feb,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 3, 1,0)) as Mar,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 4, 1,0)) as Apr,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 5, 1,0)) as May,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 6, 1,0)) as Jun,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 7, 1,0)) as Jul,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 8, 1,0)) as Aug,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 9, 1,0)) as Sep,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 10, 1,0)) as Oct,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 11, 1,0)) as Nov,
    SUM(if(MONTH(receiveDate) = 12, 1,0)) as `Dec`
FROM test 
WHERE YEAR(receiveDate) = '2012'
GROUP by type;
```

Result is:

```
type    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Blood   3   0   1   0   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   2
Sweat   2   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Tears   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```