# product quantity ordered month over month from previous year mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello I am currently training in `SQL` on `MySQL`, and I'm stuck with a problem where I want the number of products sold by category, and by month, with comparison and rate of change compared to the same month of the previous year.

Here is what I have done for now:

```sql
SELECT
    productLine,
    EXTRACT( year from orderDate) orderYear,
    EXTRACT( month from orderDate) orderMonth,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) IS NOT NULL THEN quantityOrdered ELSE 0 END) orderQuantity,
    LAG(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) IS NOT NULL THEN quantityOrdered ELSE 0 END),12) OVER (ORDER BY productLine, YEAR(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate)) orderQuantity_prevYear,
    CONCAT(ROUND((quantityOrdered - LAG(quantityOrdered,12) OVER ( ORDER BY productLine, YEAR(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate)))*100/LAG(quantityOrdered,12)OVER ( ORDER BY productLine, YEAR(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate)),0),'%') AS month_to_month_difference
FROM
    orderDetails
        INNER JOIN
    orders USING (orderNumber)
        INNER JOIN
    products USING (productCode)
WHERE
    YEAR(orderDate) > (YEAR(orderDate) - 1)
GROUP BY
    productLine ,
    YEAR(orderDate),
    MONTH(orderDate)
ORDER BY
    productLine,
    YEAR(orderDate),
    MONTH(orderDate)
    ;
```

But the problem is that when I don't have a quantity sold for a certain month, everything shifts in my lines and the values ​​are no longer the right ones. See Motorcycles 2019-9 to 2019-11 skipping 2019-10.
How can I display the months when there was no sales on a product category? I tried something with the CASE WHEN but it appear that it does not work.

Thank you in advance, and hope this is detailed enough.

Comment: you can create an array and check for each month or you need to make union for each month than you can get all the months. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744292/get-record-per-month-but-also-get-zero-if-no-records-that-month

Comment: also the easy way. 
    Build a table of all months.
    LEFT JOIN to that table. when data null show 0